Importance of resampling when establishing a cutoff for categorical data
I am reading Feature Engineering and Selection by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson, and on page 97, section 5.2 it has the following (my question is ref. the last sentence):
'Although near-zero variance predictors likely contain little valuable predictive information, we may not desire to filter these out. One way to avoid filtering these
predictors is to redefine the predictor’s categories prior to creating dummy variables.
Instead, an “other” category can be created that pools the rarely occurring categories,
assuming that such a pooling is sensible. A cutoff based on the training set frequency
can be specified that indicates which categories should be combined. Again, this
should occur during resampling so that the final estimates reflect the variability in
which predictor values are included in the “other” group.'
The idea of binning low-frequency categories as "Other" makes sense, but what does he mean by this should occur during resampling? If that helps, currently I am doing a Kaggle project where I have train and test data, but only labels for train.
